# android-async-http return json values from onSuccess method

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-async-http

I've been working on this app, i use android-async-http lib, the problem comes when i try to return the values from the json that the API send to me.

so, i have a class named SyncNotesHandler that do all the API request and need to return an object with the json inside.
Here is the class:

```
public class SyncNotesHandler {

    public SyncNotesHandler(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void getNotesFromuser(String token){
        Log.i("Debuggin", "comes around here");

        Header[] headers = {
                new BasicHeader("Authorization",token)
        };


        client.get(this.context, "http://104.131.189.224/api/notes", headers, null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {


            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject json) {
                Log.i("Debuggin","getting response");
                try {
                    Log.i("Debuggin", "Response: "+json.toString());
                    note.setTitle(json.toString());
                }  catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Debuggin","error");
                }

            }


            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.i("Debuggin","FAILURE");
            }
        });
        Log.i("Debuggin","pre-final :"+note.getTitle());
    }

    public Note getNoteResponse(){
        Log.i("Debuggin","final :"+note.getTitle());
        return this.note;
    }

    public void start(){
        this.note = new Note();
        this.notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
        this.client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        this.status = 0;
    }

    public void end(){
        this.note = null;
        this.notes = null;
        this.client = null;
        this.status = 0;
    }


    private static AsyncHttpClient client;
    private Note note;
    private ArrayList<Note> notes;
    private Context context;
    private int status;
}
```

Here i call all the actions:

```
SyncNotesHandler s = new SyncNotesHandler(getApplicationContext());
s.start();
s.getNotesFromuser("e6bc9f7c1e74cb3dd8ccde07e6edbc32");
Note note = s.getNoteResponse();
s.end();
```

If you see the code, and the flow that i think the code should follow is:
Enter the method `getNotesFromUser()` -> do the actions in `onSuccess` method -> enter the method `getNoteResponse()` and the log history should be:

```
Debuggin: comes around here
Debuggin: getting response
Debuggin: Response: {json}
Debuggin: pre-final: {json}
Debuggin: final: {json}
```

But the real log history shows antoher things, its weird, and i dont know how to solve this:

```
    03-17 12:17:56.441    7369-7369/com.example.usuario.androidadmin I/Debuggin﹕ comes around here
03-17 12:17:56.451    7369-7369/com.example.usuario.androidadmin I/Debuggin﹕ pre-final :null
03-17 12:17:56.451    7369-7369/com.example.usuario.androidadmin I/Debuggin﹕ final :null
03-17 12:17:56.878    7369-7369/com.example.usuario.androidadmin I/Debuggin﹕ getting response
03-17 12:17:56.885    7369-7369/com.example.usuario.androidadmin I/Debuggin﹕ Response: {"notes":[{"tags":[],"id":1,"body":"JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ","title":"QUE PEPSI","favorite":true,"status":false}]}
```

So the problem is that onSucces comes from another process, and first need to finish the actions called from syncNotesHandler and after do the onSuccess.
So the problem, is that i need to return the json value, but i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: There is nothing confusing(other than not understanding of basic threading) here.... That's how async methods work...

Comment: yeah i know, im new on android and working with apis, so i don't know, its confusing to me because i don't know too much.
But can you explain me? what i need to do?

Comment: Place in source code has nothing with code execution, especially if you are using anonymous interface implementation . You should start execution (get) and rest of the code should be inside onSuccess

Comment: ok, thats right, but the class is used multiples times, on different places, i need to return the json, from the onsuccess method.